# Why is this xml layout starting centre then jumping to the bottom after a second?

Tags: android, xml

Why is this xml layout ("@id/page"section) starting centre on my test phone then jumping to the bottom after a second as the app starts and proceeds? Why is the app not just starting at the bottom of the screen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/everything"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/kidozView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/page"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/linearad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-465900465381XXXX/36958XXXXX">
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/clear" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/clear"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text=" "
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="120sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/breakerimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#fff000"
        android:src="@drawable/clear" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/clear">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/aa"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bb"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cc"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dd"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ee"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ff"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gg"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/hh"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ii"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/jj"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/kk"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ll"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mm"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nn"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/oo"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/pp"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/qq"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

           <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@drawable/rr"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ss"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tt"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/uu"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/vv"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ww"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/xx"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/line5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn25"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/yy"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn26"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/zz"
               android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/clear64"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/up"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/clear" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why etc? We should see what's on the bottom of page, or no?

Comment: re statosdotcom - code added

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing tag `</RelativeLayout>` at the end of your layout XML file. Also, investigate those `android:scaleType="fitXY"` on your last ImageButton, this could demand the focus, so scrolling your screen.

Comment: I am sorry /RelativeLayout was not appearing in my question but it was in the code

Comment: That's ok. So exclude for a test that `scaleType` on your last ImageButton just to see what happens. Hey, that downvote wasn't mine... sorry.

Comment: I removed fitXY but no change.   : (   PS dont apologise, all good   : )

Comment: Well... I'm sorry, didn't help much :) Best luck.